# How to give value to the variable present in a string when this string is also a string variable?

Tags: php, oracle

I am having a variable `$query1` and in this, I have a query string and in this query string, I have used another variable `$sORp`. The main problem is that I want to give this `$sORp` variable a value at runtime without changing my string variable holding the query. Is this possible?

**Code Snippet is as below(dummy example):**

```
$query1="SELECT $sORP,name from table1 
    where $sORp=:SRC_NAME 
    group by $sORp,name 
    order by $sORp";
```

I want to assign this variable `$sORp` "SRC" and "POOL" at run time as I don't want to write query twice with different values.

**Use in code:**

```
$sORp='SRC';
$sql=$query1;
$sth = oci_parse($con,$sql);
```

And this is not working, Is there any solution for this.

And on running this PHP file the error is: **ORA-00936: missing expression**

Comment: define $sORp _before_ you define $query1 and PHP should do the rest. Or use sprintf or something.

Comment: But I want to assign the value of `$sORp` at runtime. I just tried to declare `$sORp` globally before `$query1` but the problem is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in this scripting language. `$sql` must be defined after `$sORp` .

```
$sORp='SRC';
$sth = oci_parse($con,"SELECT $sORP,name from table1 
                        where $sORp=:SRC_NAME 
                     group by $sORp,name 
                     order by $sORp");
```

If you want your can create a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) which will generate the right query on will:;

```
function foo($sORp) {
  $retVal="SELECT $sORP,name from table1 
             where $sORp=:SRC_NAME 
          group by $sORp,name 
          order by $sORp";
  return $retVal;
}

$sth = oci_parse($con,foo($sORp));
```

Comment: It worked great and cleared my future concepts to use in this program. Thanks. :)

Comment: Be careful to avoid SQL Injection security attacks.  Make sure the variable values are not taken from user input.

Answer (score 1):

Assign a value to the variable before using it in  string literal. Double quoted string literals will then automatically expand the variables used inside the double quoted string literal.

```
$sORp='SRC';

$query1="SELECT $sORP,name from table1 
where $sORp=:SRC_NAME 
group by $sORp,name 
order by $sORp";

echo $query1;

// run query

$sORp='POOL';

$query1="SELECT $sORP,name from table1 
where $sORp=:SRC_NAME 
group by $sORp,name 
order by $sORp";

echo $query1;
```

Comment: Will it be changed dynamically too, I mean can I assign `$sORp` value `"POOL"` after executing this query to execute new query having POOL in place of SRC?

Comment: No, you would have to assign a new value to `$sORp` and then make the query again

Comment: Then it is not useful bcz I have to write it twice. I can write query without variable then just replacing `$sORp` with "POOL" and "SRC"

Comment: Your problem is that you are not allowed to use bound values on table names or column names. These have to be known for the database to be able to prepare the query.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. When a string is evaluated, then its value is determined, even if you used a variable to do that and the variable later changes. You try to optimize the way you generate the string, but you prematurely optimize. The string generation will be quick in your case, at least in comparison to your query. You could minimalize the number of queries generated this way:

```
$cachedQueryTexts = array();
function generateQueryText($key) {
    return (isset($cachedQueryTexts[$key])) ? $cachedQueryTexts[$key] : ($cachedQueryTexts[$key] = "your query using the $key variable");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, buddy, but sorry as I am only a beginner I couldn't understand your answer completely. It must be of higher level. Thanks for answering. May be in future I can get a reference from it.

Comment: @ShivamSharma no problem, the basic idea was that a string will not be changed after the evaluation even if a variable used as its dependency changes, however, you can cache values to make sure you do not evaluate a string which was already evaluated.